# Navigate the selection by keyboard in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, select

I have a polygon layer with several instances (like a grid). I want to be able to change the selection with the up and down arrows. I made this code, and it worked for a while on a test polygon, but it didn't work on my original polygon and now it doesn't work on the test one either. Can someone see what I am doing wrong here ?

```
# Get the selected features from the active layer
 layer = iface.activeLayer()
 selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()

# Get the IDs of the selected features
selected_ids = [f.id() for f in selected_features]

# Check if there are any selected features
if len(selected_ids) > 0:
   # Get the first selected ID
   current_id = selected_ids[0]
   print("Selected ID:", current_id)

# Get the next or previous ID based on the arrow key pressed
def get_next_id(current_id, increment):
    all_ids = layer.allFeatureIds()
    current_index = all_ids.index(current_id)
    next_index = (current_index + increment) % len(all_ids)
    return all_ids[next_index]

# Define the up and down arrow key functions
def up_arrow():
    global current_id
    print("Starting up_arrow()")
    next_id = get_next_id(current_id, 1)
    print("Next ID:", next_id)
    layer.removeSelection()
    layer.select(next_id)
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
    current_id = next_id
    print("Selected ID:", current_id)

def down_arrow():
    global current_id
    print("Starting down_arrow()")
    next_id = get_next_id(current_id, -1)
    print("Next ID:", next_id)
    layer.removeSelection()
    layer.select(next_id)
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
    current_id = next_id
    print("Selected ID:", current_id)

# Connect the up and down arrow keys to their respective functions
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QShortcut
up_shortcut = QShortcut(Qt.Key_Up, iface.mapCanvas().viewport())
up_shortcut.activated.connect(up_arrow)
down_shortcut = QShortcut(Qt.Key_Down, iface.mapCanvas().viewport())
down_shortcut.activated.connect(down_arrow)
```

Comment: I recommend giving this plugin a try: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/go2nextfeature/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find it more reliable to connect to the [`keyPressed`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsMapCanvas.html#qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas.keyPressed) signal of the [`iface.mapCanvas()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsMapCanvas.html):

```py
selected = None

def select_next_feature(event):
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
    
    # check that there is at least one selected feature
    if len(selection) > 0:
        global selected
        
        # if one or more features are selected, use the first one
        selected = selection[0].id()
    
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            # increment the value of selected
            selected -= 1
            # clamp the min value of `selected` to the lowest id
            if selected <= 1:
                selected = 1
            
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            # increment the value of selected
            selected += 1
            # clamp the max value of `selected` to the number of available features
            # be aware this will likely cause issues if there are missing id numbers, in which case a different approach will be needed.
            if selected >= layer.featureCount():
                selected = layer.featureCount()
        
        # select the feature and zoom to it
        layer.selectByIds([selected])            
        iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
        
        # the next line I added to better show the next feature being selected in the gif
        [iface.mapCanvas().zoomOut() for x in range(4)]
        
        # update the display
        iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
        
    else:
        # inform that no features are selected
        print('select a feature first')
        
# get reference to the map canvas and connect the function to `keyPressed`
c = iface.mapCanvas()
c.keyPressed.connect(select_next_feature)

# to disconnect
#c.keyPressed.disconnect(select_next_feature)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly

Comment: A great solution, I like how you utilized the `keyPressed` event